# Div height to animate smoothly to its new height after portfolio is sorted

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, portfolio

I am in the midst of making my portfolio template but I am completely not familiar with JS, jquery and CSS transitions. Got this ( http://pixellytrain.com/sortportfolio/index.html) up and running through different tutorials. I would like to make the .blue div slide/ease nicely to the new height of the .red div after the portfolio is sorted (e.g. from "all" to "cat a").

Something like how the footer of this portfolio: http://hogash-demo.com/kallyas_wp/features/portfolio/sortable-layout/ slide in nicely when the portfolio become shorter.

Due to the portfolio tutorial on Queness, I already have got jquery, mixitup.js and easing.js linked to the page.

I tried this randomly but it was doing nothing so I am not sure how to get going or whether I am even on the right track. Thank you to all you kind-hearted pros in advance!!

```
        $('.filter').click(function () {
            $('.red').slideToggle('8000', "easeOutBounce", function () {
         });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/XY2Ju/

Here is a working implementation. Enjoy!

0) Create something that wraps everything inside .red.

```
<div class="red">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <all the stuff that makes your portfolio>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the wrapper needs overflow: hidden; in it's css.

1) When the filter is clicked, get .red's current height and set red's height to it, then it won't jump around.

```
$('.red').height($('.wrapper').height());
// The portfolio moves around
```

2) After the animation of the items is complete, set .red to animate() to the same height as the wrapper.

```
$('.red').animate({'height': $('.wrapper').height()}, 250);
```

Comment: Thanks, I learn something new. Working very well here pixellytrain.com/sortportfolio/varheight.html.

I updated it to the portfolio code pixellytrain.com/sortportfolio but it didn't work, could it be something to do with the time taken to shuffle the portfolio. 

Really thank you @KjeldSchmidt for the solution!  I will go figure it out more in any case.

Comment: Hey! I took a look at your website. I had problems really finding the code - i saw you embedded some, including mine, into your html file directly.

The problem is: The functions I have given you need to be within the same "scope", so block of code or javascript file as the function that is filtering. Since they are within a <script>-tag on their own, nothing can call them. Where does the actual filtering happen? Is it in the mixitup-library?

Comment: The actual filtering is controlled by js/jquery.mixitup.min.js . I didn't fully understand the JS script when I use them but I think the block of code above is for assigning my css selectors to run the filtering. 

Does being in the same scope mean that I will need to put the code you provided in the mixitup js file? the non- minified version-[ https://github.com/patrickkunka/mixitup/blob/master/src/jquery.mixitup.js ]

Just wondering if it will be easier if I provide you with the working folder [http://www.pixellytrain.com/sortportfolio/sortportfolio.zip]. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hey, I'll gladly help you more this evening (approxmitaley 9 hours in my timezone), I've been rather busy yesterday.

Comment: Thanks man, no rush at all. Just hope I am not troubling you too much.

Comment: Hey, no, absolutely not, I'm having fun. First of all, I realized I was wrong - the scope isn't a problem, after all, you load in jQuery in one <script>-tag and use it in all the others. See also: http://jsfiddle.net/wAAbv/
Therefore, the function alls would have to be used at some point isnide the mixitup.js. That would, however, diasble updating or at least would force you to insert he function calls over and over again. I'm looking for the correct positions to call the functions now.

Comment: Damn, thats actually harder than expect... I _think_ you should call the functions inside the _animadeTargets function on line 1220, basically at the very beginning and very end. But I'm by all means not sure this is correct. Maybe there's a documentation for the mixitup...

Comment: Reading the documents, I've found something interesting: 
https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/docs/#prop-animation-animateResizeContainer

If you set this to true at the beginnig, it should work out - though you probably won't be able to use a custom easing function.

Comment: Got it! Here's the results. [ http://pixellytrain.com/sortportfolionew/ ] Thank you if not I will still be fumbling in the dark! So awesome and enlightening. So here's the fix - my initial markup was using the Bootstrap container to wrap around the mixing container. Once I brought the mixing container up to section level controlling the entire bounding area. It automatically worked and in the end I played around with the customisation based on the docs! Felt so dumb. Haha.

Comment: Cool, I really like the looks! You're more of a Designer, aren't you? :D

Comment: Thanks :) Yea, more of a designer, trying to learn more about web development. always so much to learn. Thanks again! It is people like you that makes learning so much easier.